# Update max with condition

Tags: postgresql, max

I have table1

| grade | sums | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 197 |  |
| 4 | 187 |  |
| 4 | 154 |  |
| 2 | 1025 |  |
| 5 | 934 |  |
| 6 | 354 |  |
| 3 | 325 |  |
| 4 | 405 |  |
| 4 | 178 |  |
| 3 | 97 |  |
| 3 | 81 |  |
| 2 | 132 |  |
| 3 | 454 |  |
| 5 | 90 |  |

I am trying to get the max value of column sums based on the criteria in column grade and the output will be something like this;

| grade | sums | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 197 | 1,025 |
| 4 | 187 | 405 |
| 4 | 154 | 405 |
| 2 | 1025 | 1,025 |
| 5 | 934 | 934 |
| 6 | 354 | 354 |
| 3 | 325 | 454 |
| 4 | 405 | 405 |
| 4 | 178 | 405 |
| 3 | 97 | 454 |
| 3 | 81 | 454 |
| 2 | 132 | 1,025 |
| 3 | 454 | 454 |
| 5 | 90 | 934 |

Tried this but getting error

```
update table1 
set rate = (select MAX(sums) OVER(PARTITION BY grade) FROM table1);
```

Comment: Why do you want "OVER(PARTITION BY))"? How about `update table1 t1 set rate = (select max(sums) from table1 t2 where t1.grade=t2.grade);`

Comment: There is only 1 table, I want to update table1 based on the same table's data

Comment: Have you tried running the command that I suggested? Does it produce the desired effect? (Maybe I'm oversimplifying the problem, but maybe that's simply the solution. I also fail to understand why you would want to write a calculated value into a table column (rather than re-calculate whenever you need the information), but maybe that's a different discussion).

Comment: The suggested command is working perfectly, but taking long time to complete 1mln line of data. Is there any way to complete the report faster with any alternative query please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) would be any faster than @Hieko Jakubzik's query in the comments. But maybe? In this query, we find all of the maxes and they go in a temporary table (`tt`).

```
WITH tt as ( SELECT grade, max(sums) AS thisrate
               FROM table1
           GROUP BY grade )

UPDATE table1 t 
   SET rate = thisrate
  FROM tt
 WHERE t.grade = tt.grade
```

Comment: @ bfris The query is working super fast and more than my expectation. Can we add round option also, like 'round(thisrate FROM tt WHERE t.grade = tt.grade,2)' tried but getting error

Comment: to round, you should change line `SET rate = thisrate` to `SET rate = round(thisrate)`. Alternatively, you should also be able to do the rounding in the WITH statement.